# How to subtract column name stored in a python list from it's next name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I created a variable which stores the list of column names which I want to subtract from its neighbor

```
varlist = ['col1' , 'col2' , 'col3']
```

I wish to subtract `'col1'` and `'col2'` then `'col2'` and `'col3'` and finally `'col3'` from `'col1'`.

Just to be clear on how I created the variable:

```
varlist= list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']))
```

Comment: Hi Zoppy, welcome to SO. Are you sure they are variables? They seem like strings to me, based on the formatting. (Python interprets 'string' between ''s as string, not variable capable of holding a numerical value.)

Comment: Actually those are the name of the columns which I stored in a variable using a groupby function. The name is in str format.

Comment: oh ok sorry misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple loop on those column names? e.g. (here, `df` is the `DataFrame` whose columns we're modifying)

```py
for i in range(len(varlist)):
    # Subtract i'th column from the (i+1)'th:
    df[ varlist[(i+1)%len(varlist)] ] -= df[ varlist[i] ]
```

---

p.s. there are various ways to complicate this further: modify `varlist` instead of using `%` (modify e.g. using [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) or simply appending its first entry); use something like [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to iterate over pairs; etc., but in my opinion it is also important to keep the code readable, especially if its operation is straightforward.

Comment: I have stored the name of the columns in the varlist so when I tried doing this before it said I can't subtract str data.

Comment: Guessing: maybe you did something like `varlist[i+1] -= varlist[i]` instead of `df[varlist[i+1]] -= df[varlist[i]` ?

Comment: @Zoppy, are you sure this doesn't work for you? (if you got a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'str'`, then see my "Guess" in my comment above...)

Comment: I even mentioned its a df like you mentioned even tho the columns don't have str data type(look at edit)

Comment: Could you please take a _careful_ look at my answer and see whether it helps you?

Comment: I feel so stupid, actually I forgot to call the required libraries as the data in the cols is in date format.

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts, appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to "mark as accepted" one of the answers here, if they make sense per your original question.

Comment: It is working but in a different way, I wanted three seperate columns like in my question. This is just creating a single column after subtracting it with each other. Still helpful tho.

Comment: @Zoppy my solution does not create just one column, but modifies all columns that were mentioned in `varlist`. E.g. in your example, my simple code above is _equivalent_ to simply doing: `df['col2'] -= df['col1']; df['col3'] -= df['col2']; df['col1'] -= df['col3'];`

Answer (score 0):

0. make sure the data type of the elements in the list supports subtraction (see @zabop's comment).
1. rotate the list in order to have something like `[col3, col1, col2]`.
2. subtract the original list by the rotated list.

```py
# rotate
rotated_varlist = varlist[-1] + varlist[1:]
# subtract
varlist - rotated_varlist
```

Comment: Note: regardless of whether these are the actual columns or their names (the latter is what the OP wanted), your approach is more suitable for when we perform the subtraction operations _in parallel_, and not _sequentially_ as the OP wanted.

Comment: The problem is the ements in the list are the names of the columns which I want to subtract.